# google app engine, python , unicode, email, mail api

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unicode

I'm using an open source web service python application to send email through GAE but if the name or email body contains Arabic or Hebrew characters the application throws some errors (e.g "The indicated parameters are not valid"). Therefore I need to know how to fix this issue. I have to note that I'm a Python beginner (one week since I started playing with Python).

```
#
import cgi
import os
import logging
import contextlib
from xml.dom import minidom
from xml.dom.minidom import Document
import exceptions
import warnings
import imghdr
from google.appengine.api import images
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from google.appengine.api import mail
import wsgiref.handlers

# START Constants
CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER = "Content-Type"
CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT = "text/plain"
XML_CONTENT_TYPE = "application/xml"
XML_ENCODING = "utf-8"
"""
Allows you to specify IP addresses and associated "api_key"s to prevent others from using your app.
Storage and Manipulation methods will check for this "api_key" in the POST/GET params.
Retrieval methods don't use it (however you could enable them to use it, but maybe rewrite so you have a "read" key and a "write" key to prevent others from manipulating your data).

Set "AUTH = False" to disable (allowing anyone use your app and CRUD your data).

To generate a hash/api_key visit https://www.grc.com/passwords.htm
To find your ip visit http://www.whatsmyip.org/
"""
AUTH = False
# END Constants

# START Exception Handling
class Error(StandardError):
    pass
class Forbidden(Error):
    pass

logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

@contextlib.contextmanager
def mailExcpHandler(ctx):
    try:
        yield {}
    except (ValueError), exc:
        xml_error_response(ctx, 400 ,'app.invalid_parameters', 'The indicated parameters are not valid: ' + exc.message)
    except (Forbidden), exc:
        xml_error_response(ctx, 403 ,'app.forbidden', 'You don\'t have permission to perform this action: ' + exc.message)
    except (Exception), exc:
        xml_error_response(ctx, 500 ,'system.other', 'An unexpected error in the web service has happened: ' + exc.message)

def xml_error_response(ctx, status, error_id, error_msg):
    ctx.error(status)
    doc = Document()
    errorcard = doc.createElement("error")
    errorcard.setAttribute("id", error_id)
    doc.appendChild(errorcard)
    ptext = doc.createTextNode(error_msg)
    errorcard.appendChild(ptext)
    ctx.response.headers[CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER] = XML_CONTENT_TYPE
    ctx.response.out.write(doc.toxml(XML_ENCODING))
# END Exception Handling

# START Helper Methods
def isAuth(ip = None, key = None):
    if AUTH == False:
        return True
    elif AUTH.has_key(ip) and key == AUTH[ip]:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# END Helper Methods


# START Request Handlers
class Send(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        """
        Sends an email based on POST params. It will queue if resources are unavailable at the time.

        Returns "Success"

        POST Args:
            to: the receipent address
            from: the sender address (must be a registered GAE email)
            subject: email subject
            body: email body content
        """
        with mailExcpHandler(self):
            # check authorised
            if isAuth(self.request.remote_addr,self.request.POST.get('api_key')) == False:
                raise Forbidden("Invalid Credentials")

            # read data from request
            mail_to = str(self.request.POST.get('to'))
            mail_from = str(self.request.POST.get('from'))
            mail_subject = str(self.request.POST.get('subject'))
            mail_plain = str(self.request.POST.get('plain'))
            mail_html = str(self.request.POST.get('html'))

            message = mail.EmailMessage()
            message.sender = mail_from
            message.to = mail_to
            message.subject = mail_subject
            message.body = mail_plain
            if mail_html != None and mail_html != "":
                message.html = mail_html

            message.send()

            self.response.headers[CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER] = CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT
            self.response.out.write("Success")


# END Request Handlers

# START Application
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
                                                                             ('/send', Send)
                                                                         ],debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

# END Application
```

Comment: What python version are you using and what versions have the imported libraries?

Comment: I'll assume you mean _Hebrew_ characters. I doubt I ever run into the characters at Temple.

Comment: @Hyperboreus python version is 2.7.1 and GAE 1.4.2

Comment: @agf you're right Hebrew characters :)

Comment: Please include the actual stacktrace in your question. We can't debug based on "the error was something like this". And please restrict your code to what's relevant to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Nick Johnson seems the issue was fixed with some base64encode/decode . I think for some reasons python app didn't recognize the special characters from POST request so it was actually an issue with str(self.request.POST.get ... however now the app consumes more CPU and runs slower (due base64 encode/decode i guess)

Comment: @Michael They're not 'special characters', they're unicode strings - and calling `str` will attempt to convert them to byte strings using the default encoding. Please read this: http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Getting-unicode-right-in-Python

Answer (score 0):

```
mail_to = str(self.request.POST.get('to'))
mail_from = str(self.request.POST.get('from'))
mail_subject = str(self.request.POST.get('subject'))
mail_plain = str(self.request.POST.get('plain'))
mail_html = str(self.request.POST.get('html'))
```

I doubt you need to convert them to strings. Try without str(), it could work.